# Font file not loading on Libgdx Android

Tags: android, libgdx

I am using the following code to load font in my libgdx project.

```
BitmapFont(Gdx.files.local("fonts/test.fnt"))
```

This is working fine when i launch using Desktop Launcher.

however when I launch using Android Launcher i get the following error.

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: fonts/test.fnt (Local)
```

I am not sure What am i doing wrong here. My Android project's assets for folder contains fonts folder and has the files test.fnt and test.png.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android, assets can only be accessed using the internal file system:

```
Gdx.files.internal("filename");
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using different assets folders for both desktop and android so that you have separate copies of your files? Or are you using the same assets folder for both desktop and android?

If your are using the same assets folder, then both desktop and android have to use the ***android*** assets folder. Android is finicky in this way. So you will have to set your desktop assets folder to point to the android assets folder, then anytime you add new assets you have to add them to the android folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I initialize my fonts.

```
fontTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("assets/texture/font.tga"));
buttonFont = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("assets/texture/font.fnt"), new TextureRegion(fontTexture), true);
```

By using internal it searches your project for the folder containing the assets for me that folder is "assets" my project looks something like this:

[image: Project structure]

Eventhough I clearly have my assets packed into my project, I will get the same error when I export my application just like this.

Now here's how to solve that issue. You need to open up your exported project with something like 7z or Winrar, and manually drop in the 'assets' folder. In your case "fonts". This should should fix it, atleast I always have to do that, it never packs the assets for me.

Comment: I was using local instead of internal.

Comment: Like I said this is how I load my fonts. I would suggest packing the fonts within the app. It works seamlessly